# Populating Records From 1 table into 2 tables and retreiving ID to be used

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-insert

I have records from a **SOURCE1** table and I need to move those records into 2 different tables called **DESTINATION1** and **DESTINATION2**

I know how to copy records from the **SOURCE1** table into the **DESTINATION1** table by using a INSERT INTO SELECT statement, but I run into a problem.  What I need is when copying the **REMARKS** data from **SOURCE1**, I need to copy that into the **DESTINATION2** table, retrieve the **REFID** and copy that **REFID** into the respective record in my **DESTINATION1** table in the column **FK_DESTINATION2_REFID**.

The criteria is to copy only the records in the **SOURCE1** table with the **STATUS** of 1 and only copy the respective **REMARKS** data into the **DESTINATION2** table if its not null.  Also, is it possible to do this without a Stored Procedure, if not, not a big deal.

```
CREATE TABLE #Source1 (
RefID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
Status bit NULL,
ProviderID int NULL,
Remarks varchar(max) NULL
)

Create Table #Destination1 (
RefID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
Status bit NULL,
ProviderID int NULL,
FK_Destination2_RefID int
)

Create Table #Destination2 (
RefID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
Remarks varchar(max) NULL
)

-- Insert Records into #Source1
Insert Into #Source1 values (1,100,'Test 555')
Insert Into #Source1 values (0,400,'Test 123')
Insert Into #Source1 values (1,300,NULL)
Insert Into #Source1 values (1,500,'Test 999')
Insert Into #Source1 values (1,200,NULL)

--Drop table #Source1
--Drop table #Destination1
--Drop table #Destination2
```

Results would look like this:

```
Source1 Table
RefID       Status ProviderID  Remarks
----------- ------ ----------- -----------
1           1      100         Test 555
2           0      400         Test 123
3           1      300         NULL
4           1      500         Test 999
5           1      200         NULL

Destination1 Table
RefID       Status ProviderID  FK_Destination2_RefID
----------- ------ ----------- ---------------------
1           1      100         1
2           1      300         NULL
3           1      500         2
4           1      200         NULL

Destination2 Table
RefID       Remarks
------      ---------
1           Test 555
2           Test 999
```

EDIT:  My **#SOURCE1** table will be hold a dynamic set amount of records.  In this instance I have 5 Records.  But next time, it could be 50 records.  At each time using the **#SOURCE1** table, I will truncate the table each time and the REFID will start back to 1.  Since this is a temporary holding table for a batch of records, I need to move them permanently to the 2 Destination tables as indicated when finished so in essence they can look like the #**SOURCE1** table originally.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are using `IDENTITY` property on the #Destination tables. This means you are trying to assign a new PK to them, and it would thus remove the uniqueness / PK --> FK link to the #Source table... and it's unnecessary since your source table is already handling this. So, just remove this property from m the #Destination tables and do your inserts as you suspect. You can still add a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` on the destination tables if you want... but if this is all it is used for you should never run into non-uniqueness. Your FK will not be sequential, but that's because you are restricting what data to insert into it. If you want another `PK IDENTITY` column, just keep that separate. I have included that below as an example

```
CREATE TABLE #Source1 (
RefID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
Status bit NULL,
ProviderID int NULL,
Remarks varchar(max) NULL
)

Create Table #Destination1 (
SomePK int IDENTITY(1,1),
RefID int ,
Status bit NULL,
ProviderID int NULL,
FK_Destination2_RefID int
)

Create Table #Destination2 (
SomePK int IDENTITY(1,1),
RefID int ,
Remarks varchar(max) NULL
)

-- Insert Records into #Source1
Insert Into #Source1 values (1,100,'Test 555')
Insert Into #Source1 values (0,400,'Test 123')
Insert Into #Source1 values (1,300,NULL)
Insert Into #Source1 values (1,500,'Test 999')
Insert Into #Source1 values (1,200,NULL)



insert into #Destination2
select
    RefID
    ,Remarks
from #Source1
where
    Remarks is not null and Status = 1

insert into #Destination1
select
    s.RefID
    ,s.Status
    ,s.ProviderID
    ,d.RefID
from 
#Source1 s
left join #Destination2 d on d.RefID = s.RefID
where
    s.Status = 1

select * from #Source1
select * from #Destination1
select * from #Destination2

Drop table #Source1
Drop table #Destination1
Drop table #Destination2
```

Comment: TY.  Clarification: My #Source1 table will only be a temporary table.  I am using it as a temp place to hold records until I know all records are good.  Once they are good, in this case there are 5 records using the REFID 1-5.  But in my next batch of records, I will be deleting those records and repopulate with new records.  Maybe next time it might be 50 records using REFID 1-50.  I want to move them into 2 separate tables when I know that batch is good.  But I need the records to be relational in the two destination tables I have created that looked like the original source table.

Comment: Charles my answer fully suffices the original post, but with your comment there must be another PK from the tables that you are populating the #Source table from. Otherwise, how will you maintain integrity of relations? Currently the only other column to join on is remarks, which I am betting won't remain unique. It sounds like you are in the middle of an XY Problem, which we will need more details. http://xyproblem.info/ and on meta...https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem